# Convert str from textEdit in to float

Tags: python, pyqt

I have few textEdit fields, when I press button in ui code read data(float) from those textEdit fields and transver to function.
I used this to read from textEdit:

```
self.textEdit_LOT_SD=QTextEdit(self)
LOT_SD_r=self.textEdit_LOT_SD.toPlainText()
```

and tried this to convert string that I get to float `LOT_SD_r=float(LOT_SD_r)`, but get error `could not convert string to float`. How to convert str to float? Or maybe there is a way to save data directly as float?

Comment: What are you actually writing in the text edit? Also, why are you using a QTextEdit for value input? Do you need to use multiple lines?

Comment: Im writing there float value, only one value for a field. no, I dont need multiple lines, I was thinking to found out how to disable that. Is there other variant for single value input field? cos for output Im also using textEdit fields and it works fine @musicamante

Comment: The scope of QTextEdit is to edit and display variable text, possibly in multiple lines, with paragraphs and text formatting. This means that it's certainly *not* what you need. For single text input, use QLineEdit. For numeric input, use QSpinBox (or QDoubleSpinBox for floating point numbers). I strongly suggest you to review the full list of [widget classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widget-classes.html) and read their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the input string? Maybe it's invalid somehow.
`float(x)` is in general good approach to convert str to float in python, as long as such conversion makes sense

Try in REPL (works fine):

```
float(5)
float("2.")
float("inf")
float("-7.3")
```

Try (raises error):

```
float("xD")

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'xD'
```

Comment: Yes, i cheking input. Its always float values. Values like '3.9' or '0.5'